# Is it possible to have a binary heap containing different structs in Rust?

Tags: rust, traits, binary-heap

I'm working on an event-driven particle simulation. The code below defines the struct Event and implements the equality traits that are needed for a binary heap. This code is working but the object event built by the second constructor (new_event) has redundant member variables. I want to have a binary heap which works with two different event structs in order to avoid this redundancy and improve my code efficiency which is crucial for my project.
Can I achieve this using traits?

```
pub struct Event
{
    pub time: f64,
    pub event_type: EventType,
    pub particle_index1: usize,
    pub particle_index2: usize,
    pub particle_count1: usize,
    pub particle_count2: usize
}

impl Event
{
    pub fn new_collision(time: f64, particle_index1: usize, particle_index2: usize, 
        particle_count1: usize, particle_count2: usize) -> Self
    {

        Self {
            time,
            particle_index1,
            particle_index2,
            event_type: EventType::EventCollision,
            particle_count1,
            particle_count2
        }
    }

    pub fn new_event(time: f64, event_type: EventType, particle_index1: usize, particle_count1: 
        usize) -> Self
    {
        Self {
            time,
            particle_index1,
            particle_index2: 0, //REDUNDANT
            event_type,
            particle_count1,
            particle_count2: 0  //REDUNDANT
        }
    }
}

impl PartialEq for Event
{
    fn eq(&self, other: &Self) -> bool
    {
        self.time == other.time
    }
}

impl Eq for Event{}

impl PartialOrd for Event
{
    fn partial_cmp(&self, other: &Self) -> Option<Ordering>
    {
        other.time.partial_cmp(&self.time) //reverse order
    }
}

impl Ord for Event
{
    fn cmp(&self, other: &Self) -> Ordering
    {
        self.partial_cmp(other).unwrap()
    }
}
```

Comment: Using traits would require boxing, which is not cheap to initialize, adds an extra indirection, and a boxed trait actually is just as big as two `usize`s, so you'd actually use more memory overall.

Comment: The enum solutions bellow are the idiomatic way to solve this in Rust, and are basically as cheap as it gets. The only change I would do for performance would be to declare the fields in the order `particle_index1`, `particle_count1`, `particle_index2`, `particle_count2` for both structs, which means LLVM is able to get `particle_count1` [without branching](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=release&edition=2018&gist=0cc9763a06608383d0935234f921e682) as if only one struct actually existed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In this case it would be interesting to use an **enum** and a combination with a custom trait to avoid cumbersome access to inner enum structs:

```rust
use core::cmp::Ordering;
type EventType = String;

trait Timed {
    fn time(&self) -> f64;
}

pub struct CollisionEvent {
    pub time: f64,
    pub particle_index1: usize,
    pub particle_index2: usize,
    pub particle_count1: usize,
    pub particle_count2: usize,
}

pub struct GenericEvent {
    pub time: f64,
    pub event_type: EventType,
    pub particle_index1: usize,
    pub particle_count1: usize,
}

pub enum Event {
    Collision(CollisionEvent),
    Generic(GenericEvent),
}

impl Timed for CollisionEvent {
    fn time(&self) -> f64 {
        self.time
    }
}

impl Timed for GenericEvent {
    fn time(&self) -> f64 {
        self.time
    }
}

impl Timed for Event {
    fn time(&self) -> f64 {
        let event: &dyn Timed = match self {
            Event::Collision(event) => event,
            Event::Generic(event) => event,
        };
        event.time()
    }
}

impl Event {
    pub fn new_collision(
        time: f64,
        particle_index1: usize,
        particle_index2: usize,
        particle_count1: usize,
        particle_count2: usize,
    ) -> Self {
        Self::Collision(CollisionEvent {
            time,
            particle_index1,
            particle_index2,
            particle_count1,
            particle_count2,
        })
    }

    pub fn new_event(
        time: f64,
        event_type: EventType,
        particle_index1: usize,
        particle_count1: usize,
    ) -> Self {
        Self::Generic(GenericEvent {
            time,
            particle_index1,
            event_type,
            particle_count1,
        })
    }
}

impl PartialEq for Event {
    fn eq(&self, other: &Self) -> bool {
        self.time() == other.time()
    }
}

impl Eq for Event {}

impl PartialOrd for Event {
    fn partial_cmp(&self, other: &Self) -> Option<Ordering> {
        other.time().partial_cmp(&self.time()) //reverse order
    }
}

impl Ord for Event {
    fn cmp(&self, other: &Self) -> Ordering {
        self.partial_cmp(other).unwrap()
    }
}
```

[Playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=df4729b1ad5d0e8dbd03a18968c2f23d)

Comment: Why are you defining the Timed trait ? Is it strictly necessary or just good practice ? How will adding more event types impact on performance? Thank you very much for your help. I'm switching from c++ to rust for my physics simulations because I really like it, but I'm still trying to figure out the "rust way" of doing things.

Comment: @AndreaPari I used the timed trait so it is easy to access the attribute on the nested structs without matching them. In this case it just adds some sugar. Adding more event types should not impact on performance. Just different memory overhead maybe. This is as cheap as it gets I guess. Is pretty idiomatic too.

Answer (score 2):

It is possible with [enums](https://doc.rust-lang.org/stable/book/ch06-01-defining-an-enum.html) to have a create a data type which can represent multiple "types".

So you could do something like:

```rust
pub struct Event {
    pub time: f64,
    pub event_type: EventType,
    pub particle_index1: usize,
    pub particle_count1: usize,
}

pub struct Collison {
    pub time: f64,
    pub event_type: EventType,
    pub particle_index1: usize,
    pub particle_index2: usize,
    pub particle_count1: usize,
    pub particle_count2: usize
}

pub enum EventOrCollision {
    Event(Event),
    Collision(Collision)
}
```

So you could now have a `BinaryHeap<EventOrCollision>>`. However the `EventOrCollision` would have to implement `PartialOrd` and the other type constraints on `BinaryHeap`. You would need to use [pattern matching](https://doc.rust-lang.org/stable/book/ch06-02-match.html) around this type.

However Rust enums are constant width/size (+1 for the discriminant bit) so the binary heap would take up the same space in memory as you have currently. You would avoid initializing the extra usize fields although that is incredible cheap.

Comment: I was writting about this, gj :)